# How to use the gzip module to open a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

I am looking to read in a .csv.gz file that is in the same directory as my python script using the gzip and pandas module only.

So far I have,

```
import gzip
import pandas as pd
data = gzip.open(test_data.csv.gz, mode='rb')
```

How do I proceed in converting / reading this file in as a dataframe without using the csv module as seen in similarly answered questions?

Comment: Can't you use `pandas.read_csv` with the `compression="gzip"` option? Alternatively, why not call `gzip.open` in a context manager and use `pandas.read_csv` on the buffer?